# (GuideWire 9 ClaimCenter) Unable to return a single AssignmentSearchType

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I have a Range Input that's taking in an array of AssignmentSearchTypes for the valueRange. My task is to conditionally limit the search types based on the user's role. In particular, we want to only allow certain roles to assign jobs directly to another user. I've done this successfully, but when I actually pull up the page in a browser the "User" SearchType is always included, even when it shouldn't be.

I've tried declaring an array that only contains the desired SearchType 
`return new AssignmentSearchType[] { AssignmentSearchType.TC_GROUP }` 
but for some reason the TC_USER element still appears first in the rendered drop-down, in addition to TC_GROUP. I've stepped through the project line by line in the debugger, but it hasn't proved useful thus far.

Any ideas, Guidewire folks?

Comment: Couple of questions:
1. What type of input element is it?
2.have you verified that you are in fact using the page you think you are?  I'd assume that's a yes if you were able to debug, and hit your code, but I don't like assumptions.  I change the label of the element when weird things like that are happening.
3. I'm not super familiar with the page because I generally do PC instead of CC, however do you have a page level variable that holds search value that possibly defaults to TC_USER?  because that'd do it.

Comment: Hey Ted, thanks for your thoughtful response! You were pretty spot on, it ended up being a PCF level function higher up the ladder on the page that was adding the default. After modifying the logic there I got the behavior I was after :) I'm new to Guidewire so even some of the simpler things are still tripping me up. so much learning to be done! Hope ya have a great day!